# How to start an Android App by receiving a SMS?

Tags: java, android, sms

I have written an Application, which checks when you receive a new SMS and if its from a certain number, the app plays the ringtone. Now, the App should check if there is a new SMS even if it isn´t lauchned, and so my question is: How can I launch my App by receiving a new SMS?

I tryed to upload my existing code but it didn´t worked, I am sorry.

Answer (score 0):

To start an activity from almost everywhere you can simply call:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NewActivity.class);
CurrentActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
```

That should also work from your BroadcastReceiver which is triggered while receiving the sms.